# Making A Real-Looking Screw Head in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

My goal is to make a a head of a screw which looks really realistic. So now what I have done is the following:

```
<div class="screw"><div class="indent"></div></div>

.screw {

    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 49%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-image: url('img/nail-head.jpg');
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px #000;

}
.indent {

    height: 10px;
    width: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-image: url('img/nail-head.jpg');
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 8px #222;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 8px #222;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 8px #222;
    transform:rotate(150deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(150deg); 
    -webkit-transform:rotate(150deg);
    border-radius: 2px;

}
```

It also adds a little shadow around the screw so that it looks like it is popping out. How do I make this look "real". Any tips would be great!

Comment: Do you have some problem with just using an image instead? It would save lots of time.

Comment: That's quite a fuzzy question. What looks "real"?

Comment: @deceze: That is not really the issue here. Sure, it is open to a little bit of interpretation, but they are wanting something more realistic. That is pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, here's my try.

I have applied a grey gradient on the circle, also added border and changed the shadow.

```
box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #000, -1px -1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hfw2D/

Note: I haven't wrote the rules for all browsers (-ms,-moz, etc...). Tested on chrome.